# How to push to a Gitlab repo that you signed in with Github?

Tags: git, github, oauth, gitlab

I've signed into someone else's Gitlab repo, forked it, cloned it and made some changes, but now I can't push.

Here's what I did:

```
git push
Username for 'http://git.customgitrepo.com': mygithubusername
Password for 'http://mygithubusername@git.customgitrepo.com': mygithubpassword
remote: invalid credentials
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://git.customgitrepo.com/mygithubusername/projectname/'
```

I've also tried `mygithubusername@github.com`, but no luck. How might I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to push to the original Gitlab repo, or another copy you have made on Github? If it is the former, and assuming you have the permission, you usually need to enter your credentials for git.customgitrepo.com, not github.com.

Answer (score 0):

Bracket,

At first you have got it all wrong only you can create pull requests in someone else's repository .
You can't push without his permission(You need access to his/her repo for the direct push operation.)
But now you have one solution here:-

1) go to repository

2) Make changes in the code --> at the end of the page you will "propose file change" click on it and then create pull requests from pull requests tab

3) Reporsitory owner will get notify for your changes requests if he/she will approve than your changes pushed on the repo.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm trying to push to my fork; so I can then create that pull request.

Comment: Than prefer to this link(to fork a repo and create pull requests):-

https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo

Answer (score 0):

The way that you authenticate by using GitHub to GitLab is via OAuth, so there's no point at which GitLab gets your credentials.  Consequently, you can't use your GitHub username and password to log in, since there's no way for GitLab to verify it.

You should first change your GitHub password and then create an access token in the GitLab settings page.  This is the best way to access a repository over HTTPS when you don't have a username and password available.  You could also add an SSH key and use that instead if you prefer.